# Java util log level mapping to Jboss log level

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

My MBean is deployed on jboss. The jboss logging level is set to 'INFO'. Now when i change the logging level (java util logger) for my package to be 'FINE' (runtime programmatically by setting log level), it does not append any messages of logger.fine("...."). The messages are getting filtered out.

Is there any way to propagate the change in the log level of java util logger to jboss log level?
(There are different levels for both
java util -> SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST
jboss -> FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE)

Comment: What version of JBoss AS?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the jboss logger settings instead. I have a feeling it's actually JBoss who controls your logging configuration

If you're getting confused with multiple logging library, consider cross-library logging framework such as slf4j or commons logging, such that your code is compatible with whatever logging framework the client uses

Comment: FWIW JBoss Logging is a logging facade.